# How to create a dart handle over a js URL in Flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:js_util' as js_util;

url = html.Url(provider); // Not defined
url.hash = html.UrlSearchParams(js_util.jsify({
  'origin': html.window.location.origin,
})).toString();
```

I can create an UrlSearchParams object, but I don't know how to create an Url object.